# remove special characters from string in Java

Tags: java

I am new to `Java` and my question is: 
I am having
`String s1= "fd%gf&hgyt$#hg";`
and  the output should be like this `fdgfhgythg`.
I have tried using string replace function but not working please help me.

Comment: Please show us what yo have tried so far.

Comment: We can only help with code that you share with us. Just providing "given this input that output is expected" ... is only half of an answerable question.

Comment: I have tried like this     string s1="fd&%gf&uy*jut#gh;

Comment: Try `String s = "fd%gf&hgyt$#hg"; s = s.replaceAll("[%&$#]", "");`. Where the first argument of replace all contains every character that should be replaced with `""` - nothing.

Comment: This will keep only that what you need, with regex: System.out.println(s1.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]",""));

Comment: Thank u all... I am new to java ..sorry for silly question